# Minimum amount of edges to remove to create k connected components in an undirected graph?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, connected-components

How do I approach the problem: Minimum amount of edges to remove to create k connected components? The graph might already be a forest, though not necessarily one with k connected components, and may have cycles. It is unweighted and undirected.

Answer (score 1):

- If the graph already has at least k components, then the answer is 0.
- If the graph is a tree, then the answer is `k-1`.
- If the graph is the complete graph with `n` nodes, then the answer is `n-1 + n-2 + ... + n-k+1 = (n(n-1) - (n-k)(n-k+1))/2`.
- Without assumption, the answer can be any number between 0 and `(n(n-1) - (n-k)(n-k+1))/2`.

Answer (score 0):

If the original graph is a tree, then the removal of each edge will increase the number of connected components by 1.  After removing k-1 edges, the graph will become a forest with k connected components.

Comment: I agree, but what if it is not a tree?

Comment: @fool_of_a_took Then the answer does not depend on only k and more information is necessary to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

we can use DSU(disjoint sets) kind of thing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).